# My first python tkinter app isn't running

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk


class MyGUI:

    def __int__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        self.lable = tk.Label(self.root, text='My message', font=('Arial', 18))
        self.lable.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        self.textbox = tk.Text(self.root, font=('Arial', 16))
        self.textbox.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        self.check_state = tk.IntVar()

        self.check = tk.Checkbutton(self.root, text='show ne', font=('Arial', 16), variable=self.check_state)
        self.check.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        self.button = tk.Button(self.root, text='Show message', font=('Arial', 18), command=self.show_message)
        self.button.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def show_message(self):
        print('aaa')

MyGUI()
```

My code doesn't give me any errors it runs but the app isn't opening and i don't understang why, i followed a tutorial and the code is almost the same. His code ran and opened the app and my code didn't

Comment: Most of your code is never actually executing, because you put it in a method named `__int__` which is never called.  You want to name it `__init__`, which is automatically called when the class is instantiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simply change `__int__` to `__init__`.

```
def __init__(self):
    # [...]
```

#### The code now should be:

```
import tkinter as tk


class MyGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        self.lable = tk.Label(self.root, text='My message', font=('Arial', 18))
        self.lable.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        self.textbox = tk.Text(self.root, font=('Arial', 16))
        self.textbox.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        self.check_state = tk.IntVar()

        self.check = tk.Checkbutton(self.root, text='show ne', font=('Arial', 16), variable=self.check_state)
        self.check.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        self.button = tk.Button(self.root, text='Show message', font=('Arial', 18), command=self.show_message)
        self.button.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def show_message(self):
        print('aaa')

MyGUI()
```

To be honest, first, I thought you forgot to call the `__int__` function, but after thinking again, I realized it.

#### This method also works too:

```
import tkinter as tk


class MyGUI:
    def __int__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        self.lable = tk.Label(self.root, text='My message', font=('Arial', 18))
        self.lable.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        self.textbox = tk.Text(self.root, font=('Arial', 16))
        self.textbox.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        self.check_state = tk.IntVar()

        self.check = tk.Checkbutton(self.root, text='show ne', font=('Arial', 16), variable=self.check_state)
        self.check.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        self.button = tk.Button(self.root, text='Show message', font=('Arial', 18), command=self.show_message)
        self.button.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def show_message(self):
        print('aaa')


MyGUI().__int__()
```